# Local Fonts Breaking with Chrome & FireFox Update

Tags: css, google-chrome, jsf, fonts

Good morning!

My Team and I spent most of yesterday trying to figure out why that when I started the server yesterday morning, the website I was working on came up with every font on it displaying Times New Roman. The site is written in JSF utilizing an Eclipse Workspace, so we at first thought it was an issue with the Workspace, since the site was showing up correctly for one of my coworkers.

After hours spent rebuilding and debugging the Workspace, we came to the conclusion that it was either the code or the browser. I spent about an hour looking through the code, but could not find any issue that would cause our problem, so we concluded it was the browser. That was when one of my coworkers suggested that the person for whom the site was displaying fine on, update to the latest version of Chrome - which caused the fonts to break.

That latest version is: 38.0.2125.104 .

The code that is embedding the fonts looks like the below (the JSF resource tag just renders an HREF from the library):

@font-face {
    font-family: 'aleoregular';

```
src: url(#{resource['lib:library/ui/fonts/aleo/aleo_regular_macroman/Aleo-Regular-webfont.eot']});
src: url(#{resource['lib:library/ui/fonts/aleo/aleo_regular_macroman/Aleo-Regular-webfont.woff']}) format('woff'),
     url(#{resource['lib:library/ui/fonts/aleo/aleo_regular_macroman/Aleo-Regular-webfont.ttf']}) format('truetype'),
     url(#{resource['lib:library/ui/fonts/aleo/aleo_regular_macroman/Aleo-Regular-webfont.svg']}) format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

Or, it would look like this in CSS without the JSF:
@font-face {

```
font-family: 'sinkin_sans600_semibold';
src: url('../fonts/sinkin-sans/sinkinsans_600semibold_macroman/SinkinSans-600SemiBold-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/sinkin-sans/sinkinsans_600semibold_macroman/SinkinSans-600SemiBold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/sinkin-sans/sinkinsans_600semibold_macroman/SinkinSans-600SemiBold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/sinkin-sans/sinkinsans_600semibold_macroman/SinkinSans-600SemiBold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/sinkin-sans/sinkinsans_600semibold_macroman/SinkinSans-600SemiBold-webfont.svg#sinkin_sans600_semibold') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

On Firefox's console, I am getting this error: 
"downloadable font: FTTM: misaligned table (font-family:....)"

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of our guys figured it out! There was a server configuration filter that was corrupting the font files, they were able to modify the pom.xml file to get it all working again.

Answer (score 0):

No definitive answer, but some things to try/check...

There is no problem that I have found with the new Chrome version and fonts.

You will be getting times fonts (actually 'serif') because that is the browser default if no font is set.

I take it your web fonts are being loaded from a local server and not the internet, and that therefore you can check that those font files exist and haven't become corrupted.  Even if they are coming from the web somewhere, the next step is the same...

In Chrome, open the dev tools, and you should be able to see in the Network panel if the font file(s) are being requested and served up.

For a good call, Chrome will show the served font in the Preview tab when you click on the network call.  If you see nothing there, check the response headers.  You will need a **Content-Type** of something like **font/woff2** or **application/x-font-woff** or similar.

You can also see from the network panel whether the files are being served from cache or not.  It could be that the problem is not a Chrome version change as such, but that upgrading cleared the cache or the assets just naturally became cache expired and now are trying to fetch the problematic versions.

Could you be gzipping the font files, for example now, where you were not before (or vice versa)?

Comment: Investigating the network panel yields a 200 OK response for the requested font. The preview is Times New Roman.

Here is the request header:

Comment: GET /website/javax.faces.resource/project/ui/fonts/sinkin-sans/sinkinsans_300light_macroman/SinkinSans-300Light-webfont.woff.xhtml?ln=fdlic HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.27 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer:http://localhost:8080/website/javax.faces.resource/project/ui/css/fonts.css.xhtml?ln=fdlic&ts=141021081527-0500
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
And here is the response header:

Comment: Content-Type:application/font-woff
Date:Tue, 21 Oct 2014 14:49:00 GMT
ETag:W/"42745-1413897323059"
Expires:Tue, 21 Oct 2014 14:49:00 GMT
Last-Modified:Tue, 21 Oct 2014 13:15:23 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked

Comment: That all looks ok to me.  Guess my next step would be to try the font files locally (or at least somewhere not served up under apache) to determine whether file or server is to blame.  From the network panel you can open the file in another tab and it should download.  You could then check the downloaded file is the same as that on your server.